# node: custom emitter backing up when socket.io connection is established

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a spawn function that is continuously outputting new information. I'm monitoring the output of that spawn via the 'data' event and emitted a custom emitter that I call 'updated' that emits whenever new data is received from the spawn. After each 'data' event occurs the data stored in partialData is emitted with the 'updated' emitter and then cleared.

This seems to work fine but when socket.io is implemented, the 'data' event seems to be ran but the results in partialData don't get processed, pile up on each other, and then several occurrences of the 'data' event get emitted at once. Why is this occuring and how do I resolve this issue? In the real application I'm using this in JSON strings are being handled and the pileup is causing node to crash.

This example is a simplified version of a larger application but the symptoms are the same. The following example consists of a bash script to emit a timestamp every 1/5th of second which should be ran from the same directory as the node code. After you launch the node command the terminal will output the timestamp and length of partialData. You will notice a change in the length of partialData whenever you browse to 127.0.0.1:3000. This is the issue.

emitter.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ 1 ]]; do
    echo `date +%s`
    usleep 20000
done
```

emitter.js:

```
var express = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express');
var http = require('http');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io  = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io').listen(server);

runCommand = function (arg1) {
    var self = this;
    var partialData = '';
    var cmd = spawn(arg1);
    cmd.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    cmd.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        partialData += data.substr(0,data.length-1);
        console.log('data: '+partialData.trim());
        console.log('length: '+partialData.length);
        partialData = '';       
        self.emit('updated', data);
    });
}
util.inherits(runCommand, events.EventEmitter);

var result = new runCommand('./emitter.sh');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(
    "<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>\n"+
    "<script>\n"+
    "var socket=io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');\n"+
    "</script>\n"
    );
});

server.listen(3000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(webSocket) {
    console.log('socket established');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that the `data` event will be triggered every time your shell script has outputted a line; when other I/O takes place (like your `socket.io` example), the output is allowed to be buffered.

If you want line-support, you can use the [`readline`](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module:

```
var cmd = spawn(arg1);
cmd.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
var linereader = require('readline').createInterface(cmd.stdout, cmd.stdin);
linereader.on('line', function(line) {
  ...
});
```